# On the number of repeated roots

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, polynomials

Is there a number $c>0$ such that:

For any $n$  there is a polynomial $p(x) = a_nx^n +\cdots + a_0$ where the coefficients are $-1, 0$ or $1$ such that the number of repetition of the root $x=1$ in $p$ is at least equal to $c\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log n}}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a cute combinatorial argument by Bloch and Polya

> "On the roots of certain algebraic equations", Proc. London Math. Soc. 33 (1932), 102-114.

Consider the points $c=(c_1,\dots,c_k)\in \mathbb Z^k$ defined by $c_i=\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{r}{i-1}b_r$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k$, where the $b_r$'s are allowed to take values in $\{0,1\}^{n+1}$. The $c$ points are bounded in the region $0\le c_i\le \binom{n+1}{i}$. A simple estimate shows that for $k<\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log_2 n}}$ the number of $c$ points is less than $2^n$. That means that there exist two vectors $b,b'$ which give rise to the same $c$. Now let $a_r=b_r-b'_r$ for $r=0,\dots,n$. Define $P(x)=\sum_{r=0}^n a_r x^r$, which has coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$, then we have $0=P(1)=P'(1)=\cdots=P^{(k-1)}(1)$.